# Overriding single YUI dialog button style

Tags: css, yui

I'm trying to override the style of a button used in a single YUI dialog. I've created a css file that has

```
#mydialog.yui-button {
 // style customization
}
```

Where mydialog is the id of the dialog. This does not work. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to be more specific with the selector. if YUI is using

```
#wrapper #main #mydialog.yui-button
```

you will need something like

```
#wrapper #main a#mydialog.yui-button
```

think of it like this

HTML elements = 1 Classes = 10 ID's = 100 Inline styles = 1000

```
#wrapper=100 + #main=100 + #mydialog=100 + .yui-button=10 = 310
#wrapper=100 + #main=100 + a=1 + #mydialog=100 + .yui-button=10 = 311
```

if that doesnt work you can always resort to adding importants.
be warned that using importants instead of specificity is considered bad practice and should not be done if helped.

example:

```
#mydialog.yui-button{
    color: #000 !important;   
}
```

always after the last property value and before the semicolon.

lastly if that fails you probably dont have the correct class and/or id. also make sure your stylesheet is loading.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS class for the YUI button is not "yui-button" your rule is incorrect.  Assuming you're using "button" element for the button and not an "input", the right way would be:

```
#mydialog button {
    // style customization
}
```

Hope that helps.